# New-SelfSignedCertificate missing Signer parameter on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: powershell, ssl, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to run some pre-defined Powershell scripts that will create signed certificates however I'm coming across this error:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Signer'.

When the following call is made:

```
Get-Command -ParameterName Signer -Module PKI -Name New-SelfSignedCertificate
```

I've noticed in PowerShell ISE that the "Signer" parameter isn't appearing in the list of parameters but is mentioned on the MSDN page for the command (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps).

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 - could the issue be an outdated OS? My PowerShell version is as follows:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14409  1005
```

Comment: When was the last time the module was updated?  It could be that you're using an out of date PKIClient module.  Try `Update-Module PKIClient` and let me know if it works.

Comment: This parameter was added in Windows 10/Windows Server 2016.

Comment: @Crypt32 - I suspected that might be the case, thanks for confirming